# Android : Switch (ToggleButton) and threads

Tags: android, multithreading, layout, button, toggle

In my app targeted for Android 4.0.3, I used to have a Button working as a Switch. Clicking on the button was making its resource change (switch between Play/Pause) and some tasks were performing in the background. The particularity is that when the Button was pressed, I wanted the toggle to be unavailable for a short period of time (to prevent fast switching).

To do so, I created a thread that was waiting for X seconds, like this :

```
void blockButton(){
    new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try {
                        synchronized(this){
                             button_ready = false;
                             sleep(5000);
                             button_ready = true;
                        }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){}
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

and basically in my Activity/onClickListener

```
if(button_ready){
    // Start background stuff
    changeButtonResource();
    button.setEnabled(false);
    blockButton();
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

So far so good, everything was runnin smooth. But I eventually wished to update it to a Switch. The code is pretty much the same (except for the onClickListener that turned into a OnCheckedChangeListener).

But now when I click the button once, clicking it again will allow changing its resource - yet the background task will not start (I tried it with a Vibrator and others already, it only changes the resource).

So I almost have the behaviour my Button used to have, but the resource gets messed up. Any idea would be more than welcome ! Thanks.

Comment: Your synchronized block does not do anything (`this` refers to the thread which is a local variable and therefore not shared). How is `button_ready` declared? `volatile`?

Comment: button_ready is a regular variable in the class, and initialized within the onCreate() method. Again the method works perfectly with a simple Button, so the thread DOES do something (change var, wait, change var).

Comment: To make your code thread safe (which might or might not solve the issue): remove the synchronized block and declare your variable as volatile: `private volatile boolean button_ready;`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip (didn't solve the problem though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create another thread. `View.postDelayed(Runnable)` gives you a much easier way to enable buttons (or do other UI actions) after a timeout. Your code should look something like this:

```
class ... extends Fragment {
    private final Runnable enabler = new Runnable() { public void run() {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }};

    private View button;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = ...
        button = result.findViewById(...);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                ...
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        ...
        button = null;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        ...
        button.removeCallbacks(enabler);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        ...
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Calling `removeCallbacks` before your `Fragment` or `Activity` goes away is important to avoid concurrency problems caused by the user leaving during the disabled period. And after disabling the callback in that case, it's important to make sure you don't then get 'stuck' in the disabled state when the user comes back to your `Fragment` or `Activity` and the `View` restores its saved state.

Comment: nevermind edited comment : I forgot to change the other way ! Works perfectly. I'm still wondering why it didn't work with me old solution, but hey all I wanted is it to work ! Thanks.

Comment: If you were relying on your `if (button_ready)` thing to avoid the state change, the problem was that `ToggleButton` and `Switcher` change their checked state internally: you can't avoid that from an `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Well, I would believe that calling enable(false) on the Switch would prevent it from switching the state ! I mean I tried it without all my surrounding code - just with a button that disables it - and it worked !